# rails 2 sql and pagination

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination

I have a very large sql query and I use pagination. 
The problem is that the pagination filters data after the query, and I need to limits paginatora carried along with the request to be processed faster.

The scheme of the run:

```
@request = sql.execute("select ....")
@request = @request.paginate(:per_page => 10)
```

Comment: since you're using raw sql to get your results, you should build your own pagination system.  i don't think kaminari or will_paginate is built to handle raw sql requests.

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't the sql query that is taking the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can limit and offset the query yourself:

```
@request = sql.execute("select ... offset #{params[:page] * 10} limit #{params[:page]")
```

the problem is how to get a pagination result over that, because you actually need the total numbers of records (SELECT COUNT) and perhaps some other data, you can read a nice article that explains how to use will_paginate on custom collections, and since you are performing your own queries, you are using custom collections

here is the article: http://pathfindersoftware.com/2008/06/how-to-use-will_paginate-with-non-activerecord-collectionarray/

---

On a second review, you can do the following:

```
sql = " SELECT ..."
@request = MyModel.paginate_by_sql(sql, :page => params[:page] || 1, :per_page => 10)
```

but you have to put the results of the select within an ActiveRecord model